# Need Context when no activity is running

Tags: android, android-layout

I am displaying a pop up  from Notification of my application.But when I check my notification no activity is running from my application so in notification when I show dialogue. Dialogue throws exception because no activity is running and context which I am passing to dialogue constuctor is null therefore I need a context when no activity is running thanks in advance. Or any Idea how I can implement this thanks in advance

Comment: Will you mind showing what you have done. where you are displaying the dialogue.!

Comment: Actually my application has to send a notification and when user click on notification a pop up will open on top of my application home screen.But Scenario is Let suppose user is using  my application and application send a notification mean while user press back key and my application will pause and no activity is running now user check the notification and click on notification the dialogue which have to appear on notification click is throwing an exception because no activity is running and context is null.Can you give me any solution thanks in advance hope you understand.

Comment: which dialogue are you showing, i mean Alert Dialog.! and post some code where you are creating the dialogue. Also try creating a dialogue that extends Activity, you can set its theme as **Dialogue**

Answer (score 0):

you can make your dialog extend and Activity class and change its theme to dialog in the manifest file. in this case, you call `notification.setLatestEventInfo(YourActivityDialog.this, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);`.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with the same issue. I can't able to use the spinner in my activity. I solved this by using the `setContentView` like as following

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
}
```

Another way you can use the separate activity for you dialog. By setting activity like follows

```
style.xml

<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In AndroidManifest Declare activity like this

```
<activity
android:name="DialogActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int i) 
    {
               LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
               final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.sendemail, null);
               final View textEntryView1 = factory.inflate(R.layout.sendemail_title, null);
              to_id = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_sender_mail_id);
              from_id =(EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.id);
              pwd =(EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.pwd);


               return new AlertDialog.Builder(current_activity.this)
                   .setTitle("hello")
                   .setCustomTitle(textEntryView1)
                   .setView(textEntryView)
                   .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                   {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                       {

                    // code here...    
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                       {
                            System.exit(0);
                       }
                   })
                   .create();


    }
```

Comment: OP mentioned that no activity is currently active.!

Answer (score 0):

You may create `MyApplication` class, inherited from the `Application`, then inside that class do the following:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        .........
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
```

After that, you may use `MyApplication.getContext()` anywhere if you need a context and don't have an `Activity` lying around.

Comment: lenik when I am calling this it give me null pointer exception should I do some thing else along with this code?? Kindly give me a brief example if I have to do any configuration change. My question is how this application is called in the applicaiton??? thanks in advance\

Comment: which exactly part gives you null pointer exception?? did you make sure to inherit `MyApplication` from `Application` and don't forget to include your `MyApplication` in Android Manifest?

Comment: yeah I did the same  my application extends from Application here is my code
`public class ApplicationContext extends Application {
      private static ApplicationContext instance = null;
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate();
   instance = this;
 }
    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
}`

and android manifest code is 
`<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.white"
        android:name="MyApplication ">`
what I am  wrong?

Comment: please, add `log.w(TAG,'blah!')` inside your `MyApplication::onCreate()` to make sure it's actually gets called.

Comment: yes thanks 
now every thing is working fine but now I recieve this exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver xxxx.BReceiver: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: sorry, this is out of the scope of this question =)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your code is running in a background in an Android `Service`. If that's the case, your `Service` is a `Context` itself, so you can use it when you need one.

Of your code is running in a background thread and not in an Android `Service` (in which case you have other big problems), you could use an instance of the application context. You get one though calling [`Context.getApplicationContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29), and you can get it in the `Activity` that starts your background code and cache it for later.

Note though that there are certain gotchas with using application context, instead of activity context - for example, you can't use `LayoutInflater` from application context.