# Android alertdialog will not close first time

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog which is working fine in a normal scenario. However, when I turn the display off and device goes idle state and then switch it back on, the dialog is present and pressing back button doesn`t dismiss it from the first time. If I press cancel on 3 or 4 times it is finally dismissed.
Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: can you please share a bit of code on the parts where you instantiate, show the dialog and where you dismiss it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13245127/1487822

Comment: is your ` dialog.setCancelable();` set to true?

Comment: check the log and see if any action is fired when you press the back button. The problem might be this. When the screen wake up, it might take some time to initialize your back button.