# Getting Force Close to make AlertDialog and DialogInterface

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, android-alertdialog

Here is my code :

```
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();

            final String message = '\u00AB' + "smsmks" + '\u00BB' + ' '
                    + txtMessage.getText().toString();
            if ((phoneNo.length() > 0) && (message.length() > 0)) {
                //pilihan, mengirim citra gambar atau tidak
                final CharSequence[] items = { "Text", "Image" };
                AlertDialog.Builder kk = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
                kk.setTitle("Pilih Metode Penginputan");
                kk.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int x) {
                        Intent i = null;
                        if ("Text".equals(items[x])) {
                            sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phoneNo,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            i = new Intent(TulisPesanLontara.this,
                                    KonversiGambar.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                }).show();  

            } else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

No error found, but if i run, and i click Items, I Getting force close. Can u help me? Thanks guys (sorry bad english)

Here my logcat

11-06 15:48:27.658: D/fastDelete(5657): ============= end to process delete event ============================
11-06 15:48:28.307: I/fastDelete(5657): !!!fastDelete phase ended!!!
11-06 15:48:30.371: D/AndroidRuntime(5657): Shutting down VM
11-06 15:48:30.371: W/dalvikvm(5657): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020648)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:568)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:209)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:123)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:272)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:849)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at com.ariefspekta.smsmakassar.TulisPesanLontara$4.onClick(TulisPesanLontara.java:177)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2535)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9130)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3850)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
11-06 15:48:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5657):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 15:48:37.789: I/Process(5657): Sending signal. PID: 5657 SIG: 9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13245127/1487822

Comment: Have you added KoversiGamber.class to your manifest?

Comment: Try this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634991/android-1-6-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window

Answer (score 0):

just replace getBaseContext() with either getApplicationContext() or use ActivityName.this.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the reference of whole application  use getApplicationContext()  at the place of getBaseContext, because getBaseContext take only particular activity reference..